# Using CURL to send a post request - connection timeout issues

Tags: node.js, curl, web-applications, connection-timeout

I'm using nodejs/express to run an app hosted on my machine's (machineA) IP address, port 3000. I am able to send post requests via curl on machineA with no issues, however, when I attempt the POST request on another machine (machineB), I get this:

curl: (7) Failed to connect to machineAip port 3000: Connection timed out

Can someone shed light on why this is happening? I assume it is some security issue that is preventing the connection. I am able to ping machineA from machineB.

This is the first time I have done anything like this and I apologize if this is a repeated question. I have been searching other questions and have not been able to make sense of the responses. Most answers seem to involve PHP (which I am not using). If anything about my question is unclear, I will happily attempt to clarify.

Comment: Have you tried logging the error to console in the express route you are requesting? If an error is being thrown in the request you could read it's error code and details in the servers output console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone comes across this question with a similar issue, the problem was caused by a firewall blocking the port I was using. Since I was on campus internet connection, the solution was to email IT to lift the firewall for connections from machineA to machineB.